# TypeError : Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: jquery

My code is:

```
var dps = JSON.stringify(ReportArray[i].displaySettings);
dps = dps.slice(1, -1)
dps = dps.replace('"', "'").replace('"', "'");
```

When I load my html file I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at Object.success (xfmerFramework.js:602)
    at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at k (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)
```

Comment: it means that `dps` is null

Comment: I think that slice is only available for arrays. But you had a string.

Comment: Actually I want to remove this code. So delete this from js file. But still it is showing me this error.@vijayP

Comment: @Prafulla Delete your browser's cache.

Comment: Are you sure the 'ReportArray[i].displaySettings' returns something? As this is clear from the error that the dps is undefined and as a result 'slice' will not work.

Comment: if you removed the code and you still have the error then this is not the code that created the error

Comment: Thnak you so much. After deleting cache it is working. @kennytm

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` will return `undefined` if the input is undefined.

```
>>> JSON.stringify(undefined)
undefined
```

Please check if `ReportArray[i].displaySettings` is defined — does `ReportArray[i]` really contain the `displaySettings` property? etc.